# How to execute just 50 test cases out of 500 test cases in testNG

Tags: automated-testing, testng

There are 500 test cases in my suite. I want to select only 50 test cases and execute them. Is there a way to do it using testNG

Comment: What's your selection rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tag before the test cases you want to execute, first add this tag to your java classes

```
@Test(groups={“Smoke”})
```

and then go to your XML file and add the following lines of code just below your suite test.

```
<test name=”Regression”>
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name=”Smoke"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="test.seleniumpractice"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

This way only test cases with the tag "Smoke" will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The ISuiteListern allows you to inspect your suite before and after its execution.

This way, you can intercept the suite before the execution and "edit" the test list as you wish.

See [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml) how to implement listeners and [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader) how to implement a ISuiteListern.